# Powershell: Moving named files to their corresponding folder

Tags: powershell, file-move

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KFfbe.png)I have a folder which has a bunch of files named:  WBF123456, WBF135464, etc. These files need to be moved to the corresponding folder. At the moment I am using the commandline to manually enter the numbers of each file so they get moved, using this code:

```
$files = $args[0]

mv O:\SCAN\SecSur\*$files.pdf O:\SPG\G*\*\*$files
```

How can I automate this process?
It needs to identify the number in the filename,  then move it to the folder containing the same number.
Any help would be great. Thanks.

I need to get the files on the left, inside the corresponding folders on the right.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the below solution will help you. You should change `$origin_path` and `$destination_path`

```
    $origin_path= "C:\Users\geralexgr\Desktop\kati\files"
    $destination_path = "C:\Users\geralexgr\Desktop\kati\folders"
    Get-ChildItem $origin_path -Recurse -Include *.txt | ForEach-Object {
        $folder = [regex]::Matches($_.Name, "\d+(?!.*\d+)").value
        Move-Item $_.FullName $destination_path\$folder
    }
```

The example will place files under the folders that match the numeric regex.

[image]

*After powershell execution file WBF12 gets inside 12 folder*

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Apparently the files to move are .pdf files, so what you can do is get a list of those files in the source folder and then loop over that list to create (if needed) the destination subfolder and move the file there.

Try:

```
$destinationRoot = 'O:\SPG\G\SomeWhere'  # enter the root folder destination path here

$filesToMove = Get-ChildItem -Path 'O:\SCAN\SecSur' -Filter '*.pdf' -File
foreach ($file in $filesToMove) {
    $numName = $file.BaseName -replace '\D+'  # leaving only the numbers
    # create the target path for the file
    $targetFolder = Join-Path -Path $destinationRoot -ChildPath $numName
    # create that subfolder if it does not already exist
    $null = New-Item -Path $targetFolder -ItemType Directory -Force
    # now, move the file
    $file | Move-Item -Destination $targetFolder
}
```

---

Seeing your screenshots, this might be a better approach for you.

```
$destinationRoot   = 'O:\SPG\G\SomeWhere'  # enter the root folder destination path here
# get a list of target folders for the files to be moved to and create a lookupHashtable from their names
$targets = @{}
Get-ChildItem -Path $destinationRoot -Directory | Where-Object {$_.Name -match '(\d+)'} | ForEach-Object {
    $targets[$matches[1]] = $_.FullName  # key is the number, value is the directory fullname
}

# get a list of files to move
$filesToMove = Get-ChildItem -Path 'O:\SCAN\SecSur' -Filter '*.pdf' -File | Where-Object {$_.Name -match '\d+'}
foreach ($file in $filesToMove) {
    $numName = $file.BaseName -replace '\D+'  # leaving only the numbers
    # see if we have a target folder with that same number in its name
    if ($targets.ContainsKey($numName)) {
        $targetFolder = $targets[$numName]
        Write-Host "Moving file $($file.Name) to $targetFolder"
        $file | Move-Item -Destination $targetFolder
    }
    else {
        Write-Warning "Could not find a destination folder for file $($file.Name).."
    }
}
```

Comment: The target folders already exist and are named  "name_name_123456".   Is it possible to put them in those existing folders?

Comment: @c00per Only is somehow the part `name_name` can be deduced from...?

Comment: I added a link at the top with a screenshot of what I mean.  I need the files on the left to go into the corresponding folders on the right.      Thanks for your time, I hfind it hard to explain what I mean.